# Greedy algorithm for coloring verticies proof explanation and alternative proofs

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, algorithms, proof-explanation, coloring

> A proper vertex colouring of a graph $G$ is a function $\kappa$ defined on
>   the vertices of $G$ such that if $v$ and $w$ are any two neighbouring
>   vertices, then $\kappa(v)$ does not equal $\kappa(w)$. A simple result in
>   graph theory is the following: let G be a finite graph such that each
>   vertex has degree at most $d$. Then there is a proper colouring of $G$
>   that uses at most $d+1$ colours. (This means that the function $\kappa$
>   takes at most d+1 distinct values.)
>
> To prove this, we choose some ordering of the vertices:
>   $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ and colour them inductively as follows. Having
>   coloured $v_1,\dots,v_{k-1}$, we would like to colour $v_k$. By
>   hypothesis, $v_k$ has at most d neighbours, so there are at most d
>   neighbours of $v_k$ amongst the vertices $v_1,\dots,v_{k-1}$. Therefore,
>   there are at most $d$ colours that we must avoid when choosing a colour
>   for $v_k$. Since there are $d+1$ colours available to us, we can
>   arbitrarily choose some colour that is not one of the ones we have to
>   avoid. And thus the induction continues.

So this proof is saying that no two adjacent vertcies numbered from one to $k-1$ is of the same color?

$v_k$ has at most d neighbors means that $v_k$ is at most connected to $d$ vertices?

If $d=5$, then we must avoid 5 colors. We have $d+1=6$ colors available that we can choose. Shouldn't $d+1$ include the 5 we must avoid, so the number of colors available to color with  is actually one or not $d+1$? But this is a contradiction. In fact, I think we don't know how many colors on the color palette we can choose.

Could we prove this by well-ordering principle?

I think I'd prove this via contradiction instead.

This proof doesn't mention the function $\kappa(v)$ once. Why is $\kappa(v)$ mentioned?

Comment: Generally, one is advised against doing a proof by contradiction when it's not necessary. A direct proof is usually a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So this proof is saying that no two adjacent vertcies numbered from one to $k-1$ is of the same color?

Well yes, but more usefully it's saying that between those vertices which are adjacent to $v_k$, there are at most $d$ colours.

> If $d=5$, then we must avoid 5 colors. We have $d+1=6$ colors available that we can choose. Shouldn't $d+1$ include the 5 we must avoid, so the number of colors available is actually one?

I think you're getting confused between the number of colours in our palette, and the number of colours we can validly assign to $v_k$. There are $d+1$ colours in our palette, but at most $d$ of those would result in an invalid colouring if applied to $v_k$.

Therefore, we always have at least one choice of colour for $v_k$ which will result in a valid colouring.

> Could we prove this by well-ordering principle?

I don't see how the well-ordering principle is necessary or useful here.

Comment: Are the neighbors of a vertex $v_k$, those adjacent to $v_k$?

Comment: Yes, in this context neighbour means "vertex adjacent to".

Comment: Sorry, last edit: This proof doesn't mention the function
κ
(
v
)
 once. Why is
κ
(
v
)
 mentioned?

Comment: $\kappa(v)$ is simply shorthand for "the colour we assign to $v$".